# Mobile app doesn't order by favourite tags

Tags: discussion, ios-app

I've noticed recently that when I open up Stack Overflow via the iOS app, my favourite tags don't seem to play a part in displaying me relevant questions. [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260138/so-mobile-site-doesnt-highlight-favourite-tags) addresses highlighting issues, but my mobile display is populated by questions that I have no experience in answering:

[image: Mobile app view]

Vs the Stack Overflow desktop or mobile website:

[image: Mobile web view]

## Question

I find this annoying - is there any reason that this occurs? Is it simply missing the "order by favourite tag relevance" criteria from the query?

I'd love to be active in the Java, C# tags etc but my involvement with Stack Overflow currently is focused towards PHP, SQL, jQuery etc...

Comment: I guess it's because the app takes the question from [`/questions/active`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active), whereas the desktop/mobile homepage show [`/interesting`](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting). Also, seems this issue applies to all SE networks. Perhaps moving it to [meta.se] is a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tap on the arrows next to the search bar, then choose **"Unanswered: My Tags"**, you will get almost what you want. I have also changed this in the beta release so that questions under this filter will ordered by most recently asked.

Comment: Suggestion: maybe an option to enable this as the default view?

Comment: Once you choose it, it will be the default sort for that site. (The app will remember the setting)

Comment: @scrowler I'm seeing similar complaints, so I will seriously consider making this the app default.

Comment: This doesn't give what you want - the questions here are ordered by votes and some of them are years old.

Comment: @jrturton this has actually been changed in the latest beta release, and will change soon on the Appstore app. See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245503/232374)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the update!