# Alternate sorting schemes for "My Tags" in mobile app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, ios-app, unanswered-questions

I love that the mobile app now has a filter option for "My Tags", but I can't seem to figure out the sorting algorithm. It seems pretty scattered and never seems to show the questions in any particular order. For instance, on my list, the question at the top is always from 2013. It's been answered twice and is probably never going to get marked as answered.

[image: Screenshot of my "Unanswered: My Tags" list]

I know there have been questions with my tags asked more recently than this. I propose a couple of different filter/sorting schemes:

- Unanswered: My Tags - sorted by most recent
- Most Recent: My Tags - including answered

These will give me the two most common use cases I have:

1. Answer questions that haven't yet been answered that I actually know something about.
2. Look at other answers from recent questions to see if I should up/down vote them.

On a related note, sometimes, questions show up in this particular filter that don't even have my tags.

Comment: By the way, I will mark this as status-completed for now, but if you feel strongly abut the "Most Recent: My Tags - including answered" filter, please file a separate feature request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the screenshot carefully, you can see that "Unanswered: My Tags" are sorted **by votes**.

I agree, as you've pointed, that sorting these by most recent is much more useful, so I've made that change, which will show up in the next beta build, version 1.2.0.169. It will then be released with our next app update (probably 1.2.2 or later).

[image: New "Unanswered: My Tags" sorting]

Regarding your request for "Most Recent: My Tags - including answered": We do not currently have an API to support this on question listing. However, you *could* use the Tags screen to get a similar result, (although separately for each tag): sort by your Favorite tags, and then, for the questions listed under each tag, you can sort them as "Newest".

Comment: Great! I can deal with not having the latter right now. It'll be nice if/when it comes but the first thing was more important.

Comment: @WesleyBland You can use the `intags:mine` operator in the search too, and then sort by newest/active.